# What is the name of this kind of tree?

Tags: identification

This kind of tree seem to be very common in Sydney, Australia.

I have captured two photo to show the leaves and...

[image]

the trunk

[image]

Could you identify the kind of tree?

In addition, I have googled before I posted this question. owever I couldn't find any website that specifically lists popular trees in Sydney or major cities. Do you happen to know such website? (So I don't have to post relatively less value-added question to Stack Exchange)

Comment: Bamboo has identified the plants, I will try to answer the other part. Cities keep maps of what trees are planted. Around here you would contact the local municipality's Park and Rec Department. If you are wanting to know what trees are popular in cities Cornell University's Hort department has put out a guide called Recommended Tree Urban - Site Assessment and Tree Selection for Stress Tolerance. Municipal parks dep. have known about stress tolerance for years, so this guide will be similar to what they do. hort.cornell.edu/uhi/outreach/recurbtree/pdfs/~recurbtrees.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a very familiar tree to me, living in London UK - it looks remarkably like a London Plane tree, *Platanus acerifolia*. To my surprise, according to this Wiki entry https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platanus_%C3%97_acerifolia, this is a commonly used street tree in parts of Australia, including Sydney, so that seems to be what it is.

The trouble with trying to work out what a plant is because its growing in a particular region or area of the world is that doesn't necessarily make it any easier for ID purposes because of the spread of non endemic plants round the world, its only helpful in wild regions where native plants are present. Whether there is a site about Sydney and its planting I don't know, but possibly some tourist information might carry some detail regarding that.

Comment: If you were living in the US , it would be a variety of sycamore.

Comment: The American sycamore is another variety of Platanus - its Platanus occidentalis, though I'm aware the common name sycamore also applies to other trees in the USA

Answer (score 1):

London Plane tree
http://www.cityofsydney.nsw.gov.au/__data/assets/pdf_file/0017/130238/STMP2011_150501-PartB.PDF
page B19

in general, search the .gov.au domain with "tree" and "council" and the name of the town or city.